# Required name in order to proceed into the app.

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am currently building a hybrid app using JavaScript, Angular JavaScript, HTML and CSS. The function that I am having problem coding is the user has to enter their name in order to proceed to the swipeable page on the right and then click 'enter app' here is the code I have so far:

```
<ion-slide>
  <h4 style="margin-bottom:10%">my name is {{name}} </h4>
  <label class="item item-input" style="width: 80%; margin:0 auto;">
    <input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-keypress="redirectMe($event)" >  </input>
  </label>    
</ion-slide>
```

Would it be possible to do something a long the lines of 'ng-show if input is not null'

Comment: You can use `$scope.$watch()` in the controller to subscribe to the `name` value. From there you can control what to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use and test directly the value of ng-model in the view.
Here you can use ng-show="name"

```
<ion-slide>
  <h4 style="margin-bottom:10%" ng-show="name">my name is {{name}} </h4>
  <label class="item item-input" style="width: 80%; margin:0 auto;">
    <input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-keypress="redirectMe($event)" >  </input>
  </label>    
</ion-slide>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7hgdvbec/